# Solve bash script without goto

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bash script that I want to do something like

```
read one_thing
read another_thing
```

And then it runs some code to see if `another_thing` is available or already taken, and if it is taken, it should warn the user and again run

```
read another_thing
```

so we can have a new value, leaving `one_thing` undisturbed. Since there's no `goto` in bash, I'm wondering how to do that. My best guess so far is that maybe I should wrap `read another_thing` inside a function, so that if needed, it will just call itself, but I feel there must be a “cleaner” way to do it. I'm looking for suggestions on efficient ways to do it.

Comment: This question would be better suited to stackexchange. Anyway, just enclose your read statement in a while loop, something like `while $a==0` and change $a to 1 when another_thing has been read correctly.

Comment: Provide some real code so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Scripts and some scripting language questions are *ok* on SuperUser however most programming issues are better solved using StackOverflow.

Comment: This question may stay here. We've always considered bash scripts on topic, since they're mostly used by power users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for your condition in a loop, and `break` out of it when it’s met.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Input something > ' one_thing

while true; do
  read -p 'Input something else > ' another_thing

  # Write some code to check if the requirements are met
  # Let's say in this case they are when the variable `thing_to_work` equals `done`

  if [[ "${thing_to_work}" == 'abcde' ]]; then
    break # Exit the loop
  else
    echo 'The requirements were not met, so the loop will start again'
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

When I moved from Windows to Linux on my desktop, I had a lot of pre-existing `.BAT` and `.CMD` files to convert and I wasn't going to rewrite the logic for them, so I [found](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/) a way to do a `goto` in bash that works because the `goto` function runs `sed` on itself to strip out any parts of the script that shouldn’t run, and then evals it all. *The below source is slightly modified from the original to make it more robust:*

```
#!/bin/bash

# BAT / CMD goto function
function goto
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/^:[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*${label}/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | 
          grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}

apt update

# Just for the heck of it: how to create a variable where to jump to:
start=${1:-"start"}
goto "$start"

: start
goto_msg="Starting..."
echo $goto_msg
# Just jump to the label:
goto "continue"

: skipped
goto_msg="This is skipped!"
echo $goto_msg

: continue
goto_msg="Ended..."
echo "$goto_msg"

# following doesn't jump to apt update whereas original does
goto update
```

and I do not feel guilty at all as Linus Torvalds famously said:

> From: Linus Torvalds
>   Subject: Re: any chance of 2.6.0-test*?
>   Date:  Sun, 12 Jan 2003 11:38:35 -0800 (PST)
>
> I think goto's are fine, and they are often more readable than large amounts of indentation. That's *especially* true if the code flow isn't actually naturally indented (in this case it is, so I don't think using goto is in any way *clearer* than not, but in general goto's can be quite good for readability).
>
> Of course, in stupid languages like Pascal, where labels cannot be descriptive, goto's can be bad. But that's not the fault of the goto, that's the braindamage of the language designer.

[Source for code](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/)  (modified to make it less error prone)
[Source for quote](http://koblents.com/Ches/Links/Month-Mar-2013/20-Using-Goto-in-Linux-Kernel-Code/)

Comment: Excellent use case and creative solution!